# fatal error: 'algorithm' file not found while running Debian Linux

Tags: linux, include, clang++

I recently updated my clang++ compiler in my debian Linux to version 3.5. I compile my file using clang++ with the line in terminal

```
clang++ -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -c -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp
```

what show up afterward is

```
main.cpp:5:10:fatal error: 'algorithm' file not found
#include <algorithm>

1 error generated
*** [main.o] Error 1
```

but when I tried using

```
locate algorithm
```

There are many file in the /usr/include/c++/4.6/ showed up, so I believe that the file are in there. I am new to Linux and if possible, please make explanation to be more detailed.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: how many module have you in your `c++` code ?

Comment: You need to install a newer libc++...

Comment: Could you explain how to install newer libc++? Sorry I am very new to Linux